# Application Token based Request returning not 401 Unauthorized

Tags: azure, azure-authentication, azure-data-catalog

I have a background application which is supposed to connect to Data Catalog and fetch information related to a table. Since its a background application, I cannot have any user intervention to authenticate the Data Catalog request. So I am trying to authenticate using ClientID and ClientSecret instead.

```
string authorityUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{adtenanthere}";

string resourceUri = "https://datacatalog.azure.com";

string clientId = "{clientidhere}";

string clientSecret = "{clientsecrethere}";

AuthenticationContext authContext1 = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUri, false);

ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);

AuthenticationResult authResult = authContext1.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceUri, credential).Result;

string token = authResult.CreateAuthorizationHeader();
```

Getting the token using this method is being successful, however when I use this token for the Data Catalog API request, the request returns "401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials. You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials you supplied".

Please suggest what I could be missing here!

Answer (score 0):

First Check Your Application Permission in Azure Ad Permission. I was check No permission in Application Azure data catalog. So, you must access using user credentials.below see the images

> Application permission is based on client credentials. the delegate
>   permission based on login user permission.

you should need without login popup you must pass the user credentials
in `authContext1.AcquireTokenAsync` directly.

[image]

[image]

So, Change and Check the you not get 401 Unauthorized

I think it's help for you.

Comment: Monica given authority url and resource url also check one it's a correct values

Answer (score -1):

Some data is incorrect, here are the correct values:

string authorityUri = "https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize";
string resourceUri = "https://api.azuredatacatalog.com";

Hope this helps,
Monica